# How Easy Is It To Triple Boot Windows 7, Ubuntu 13.10, and Arch Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

So I am getting real tired of Ubuntu. I want to switch to Arch, but keep my old Windows 7, and Ubuntu installs for future use.  I was wondering how easy it was to install Arch along side the two other operating systems.  Do I have to change anything with my boot loader?  I am currently using the default GRUB that comes with an Ubuntu 13.04 install.  It may be worth noting that I do not have a separate home and / directory, so I will have to make all of my files separate.  Thanks!

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/180951/advanced-partition-plan-for-triple-boot-windows-7-ubuntu-arch?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arch linux is for more experienced users. If you don't know how to setup a triple boot with two linuxes then it is very likely that you won't be happy with Arch.

But if you still want to experiment:  During the Arch install you can skip installing a boot-loader and then your present GRUB will be kept. (That means you just don't issue commands which install a boot-loader.) If you do this then after the installer finishes and you reboot the Arch won't be present in the GRUB menu. You will have to boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`, which will find Arch and update the GRUB menu. After this you can boot Arch from the original GRUB which came with your Ubuntu. I think this is the most simple way to setup a triple boot with Arch and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a reason to change GRUB settings yet but it shouldn't be an issue, in theory you could have as many OS's as you have partitions/HDD's.

since my PC tries to load windows first i used *EasyBCD* to setup my Dual boot, but you have the option to add OS's to your hearts content (space permitting).

Comment: So it will automatically add Arch to the list of operating systems I get upon start up?

Comment: I've never installed Arch, but if its anything like Ubuntu's installer then it should setup the GRUB settings for you. though if GRUB from ubuntu is the first thing you see you will have to configure this manually. Also you could always fall back on easyBCD, i plug it alot but its what i use since its pretty user friendly.

Comment: @Sharkytrs It is nothing like the Ubuntu installer. The Arch installer has only text mode and the user has to issue every command by hand.

Comment: nice, then I recommend learning as much Unix commands as possible before installing Arch ;P